# how to draw svg polygon on the points of mouse click position

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a project: on mouse clicks and move and next click and so on; by every click's position I want to make an svg polygon but I don't have any idea as to how.

[image: when mouse move same time polygon's last point appearing at mouse pointer and when I click and move, the clicked position get a vertices point and so on]

When the mouse moves, at the same time the polygon's last point is appearing at the mouse pointer and when I click and move, the clicked position get a vertices point and so on.

Comment: Polygon is a closed figure, what you have is polyline. Which one you really need?

Answer (score 1):

here is a code example you want.
Polygon needs to be closed you should use polyline

```html
<svg id="svg" height="500px" width="500px" style="border: 1px dashed #dbd2d2;">
<polyline id="polyline" style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1"/>
</svg>

<script>
  const polyline = document.querySelector('#polyline');
  const svg = document.querySelector('#svg');
  svg.addEventListener('click',(e) =>{
      let pts = polyline.getAttribute('points') || '';
      const newPoint = `${e.clientX},${e.clientY} `;
      pts += newPoint;
      polyline.setAttribute('points',pts); 
  })
</script>
```

Update:
For mousemove functionality add this code

```html
<svg id="svg" height="50%" width="50%" style="border: 1px dashed #dbd2d2;">
<polyline id="polyline" style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1"/>
<line id="templine" style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1" />
</svg>

<script>
let lastPt;
const polyline = document.querySelector('#polyline');
const svg = document.querySelector('#svg');
const templine = document.querySelector('#templine');
svg.addEventListener('click',(e) =>{
    let pts = polyline.getAttribute('points') || '';
    const newPoint = `${e.clientX},${e.clientY} `;
    pts += newPoint;
    polyline.setAttribute('points',pts); 
lastPt = [e.clientX,e.clientY]
})

svg.addEventListener('mousemove',(e) =>{
    templine.setAttribute('x1',lastPt[0]);
templine.setAttribute('y1',lastPt[1]);
templine.setAttribute('x2',e.clientX);
templine.setAttribute('y2',e.clientY);
})
</script>
```